# Not recognising any of the items on sd card

Tags: sd-card

Good Day, my Sony Xperia "Go" froze earlier and so I held in the power button together with the volume up button which then rebooted the phone however once I got the phone on it is recognising the sd card but it doesn't pick up any of my photo's on the sd card, please help me

Comment: *but it doesn't pick up any of my photo's on the sd card,* -- Should I take it as you can't see any photo in the Gallery? Otherwise, what do you mean by not picking up? Please [edit] and mention it.

Answer (score 0):

**If** you mean the files on your SD card are not coming up in any app that used to see them, you may have a corrupted SD card from the forced power cycle. Try mounting the SD card on a desktop computer and see what it says. Use scandisk or fsck on it, but not in repair mode. If it shows errors, but you cannot get to the files, try repairing it, copy **ALL** the files to the desktop computer, then have your phone reformat the card. Then go back to your desktop computer and reload everything.